# How to add a Viewer from libQGLViewer, without using a .ui file

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I've been writing my user interface directly instead of using the Qt UI design option, and I'm having trouble adding a Viewer panel.

I've copied the interface.h and interface.cpp files from this example code: http://www.libqglviewer.com/examples/interface.html, into my project, and attempted to insert a Viewer panel via the following code:

```
QGroupBox *groupBox;
groupBox = new QGroupBox();

QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;

Viewer viewer = new Viewer(groupBox);
textEdit = new QTextEdit;

mainLayout->addWidget(viewer);
mainLayout->addWidget(textEdit);

groupBox->setLayout(mainLayout);
setCentralWidget(groupBox);
```

but when I try to build, I get:  `error: C2664: 'QBoxLayout::addWidget' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Viewer' to 'QWidget *'`

From what I can see in the ui code, the exact same command is used, and I can't see where the difference is:     `vboxLayout->addWidget(viewer);`, and the type isn't converted anywhere else.

Any ideas? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is very suspicious:

```
Viewer viewer = new Viewer(groupBox);
```

Try with:

```
Viewer *viewer = new Viewer(groupBox);
```

Comment: Good catch! That has indeed fixed it. Thanks for your help.